# battery related info android

Tags: android

I am just tyring to create an activity which shows the battery level in the picture format automatically when ever there is a change in the battery status so any one can suggest me the procedure to create that type of app

Answer (score 3):

Information related to the battery manager can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

It's used in conjuntion with the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED Intent, which fires every time there is a change in the battery state (charge level, connected, fully charged, etc).

Comment: tnx for the info provide but i am trying to get the change in the picture automatically so...........

Comment: What does that mean? You don't want to actually code the logic for your application? I guess you could look out for an already made custom widget that does it for you. Otherwise, you will have to receive the action changed intent, and modify your image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some inspiration from the Android Settings's source code(mainly in the package:  com.android.settings.fuelgauge).

http://grepcode.com/search?query=PowerUsageSummary&n=

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java#PowerUsageSummary